# How to find database host url in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

i have a website with Joomla 2.5.4, in the configuration file the DB host is coded as localhost. i know the DB name, username, password to access. But not the URL to access the Host. is that Possible to get the information without logging in to C PANEL etc..

in some situations my client fails to give me the url to access DB, if iopen the configuration file, there it says LOCALHOST.

Is there any other way to find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `configuration.php` has `localhost` then it should be the same as the website/the ip address of the website. Remember ['localhost' is just a synonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) for *the current computer*.

I'm not sure why you would want the URL though.

If you're writing a software extension for Joomla! you don't need the database details you can just get the database object from the framework, eg. `$db = JFactory::getDBO();`

If you writing a PHP script external to Joomla! you can just use `localhost` in your connection code e.g..

```
$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
```

To check for errors in the connection you would the check the value in `$mysqli_connection->[connect_error][2]`

If you want to do a remote connection then the websites address will generally do if the configuration states localhost (*obviously if it doesn't have local host or an equivalent then the value will be the database servers address*), but you will also need to [setup the remote access through cPanel](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/SetupRemoteMySQL).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afaid you cannot find this information in other way than through your webhost, at least not to my knowledge.

localhost is the most usual way, but there are most likely other host adresses like: mysql.yourhost.com or by ip: 123.456.456.7

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem. I left the host name as 'localhost' when the files are in the file server. Then it works fine for me. If its not working fine for you,just put your domain name instead of localhost (or) otherwise file hosting service provider needs to provide the details of host name when you signup.